# Divs are not clearing floats

Tags: html, css

I have striped out the php in my fiddle so you can get an idea of the css issue. [My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamdanbarrett/J9XGp/), The problem is that there are two columns, one on the left and one on the right, whenever theres a vast amount of content in the right column the div isnt clearing or pushing out the way anything below it, initially the problem was it was turning it into a frame - so I removed the problem but now thr right column is overlapping the sections underneath??

Here is an image to explain visually:

[image]

```
<div class="wrapper" style=" height: auto; overflow: visible;">
    <div class="columnsContainer" style="height: auto; overflow: visible;">

        <div class="leftColumn">




               <div class="bodyheadertop" style="background-color:#498d7b;">
                        <h3>For sale</h3>
                    </div>
                        <div id="triangle-topright" style="float:right; border-top: 25px solid #498d7b; margin-bottom: 40px;">
                        </div>
                            <div style="clear:both;"></div>



    <div class="salespost">
        <div class="salespostleft">
            <h4><a href=""></a></h4>



                <ul>

        </ul>

        </div>




<div  class="salespostright">

</div>




<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>



</div>



<div class="rightColumn">



<div class="bodyheadertopalt" style="background-color:#498d7b;">
<h3>Successful Sales</h3>
</div>

<div id="triangle-topright" style="float:right; border-top: 25px solid #498d7b; margin-bottom: 40px;"></div>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>


                </div>
                <div  class="soldpostright"></div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </div>

            <?php } ?>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the offending code.

Comment: why you are not using `overflow: hidden;` on class `wrapper`. Remove `overflow: visible;` from everywhere.

Comment: If I remove it then the div disappears underneath the div below that it is meant to be clearing?

Comment: by seeing the picture I can understand this is the matter of not clearing the float `property`. either you can use `clearfix` method or use overflow:hidden .

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the issue. The problem was I was using em's to calculate my two columns. I have switched this to pixels and resolved the matter.